# SharePoint User Profile Site Link

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

Is it possible to have one link/button on sharepoint that a user can click on and it redirects them to their personal site?

I have a user site setup with the same site name as their AD profile login.

AD profile: bob.smith

Site URL: sharepoint.com/sites/bob.smith

Can I create a button that has something like sharepoint.com/sites/[ME]

Thanks for the input and tips. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a link to the my site host. This site was created when personal sites were enabled. The host site will automatically redirect the user to their correct site.

This [answer](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/16607/how-to-enable-mysites) gives an overview of the setup of a my site host for SharePoint 2010.